# IBM DB2 NEXT VALUE FOR concern

Tags: sql, db2

I am wondering when using the NEXT VALUE FOR does it lock the data area in the background? I want to make sure it does not create duplicate sequence numbers.

Comment: Locks data? Don't worry, no duplicates will be returned.

Comment: Locks data area  -- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rbam6/dalal.htm

Comment: That link refers to the CL programming language, not to SQL.  I don't think sequences have any relation to the "Change Data Area" or the "Retrieve Data Area" or the "Display Data Area" - at least [the documentation for sequences](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzsequences.htm) does not even mention those.

Comment: I know that. The point I was trying to make is it generate a unique sequence number every time. I know by createing a lock in CL, pretty much guarantees that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Db2 for i-Series, the reference documentation for [sequence](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzseqref.htm) is here.

The [reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023464.html) documentation (for Db2-LUW) has what you need.

> When a value is generated for a sequence, that value is consumed, and the next time that a value is requested, a new value will be generated. This is true even when the statement containing the NEXT VALUE expression fails or is rolled back.
>
> However, if there are multiple instances of a NEXT VALUE expression specifying the same sequence name within a query, the counter for the sequence is incremented only once for each row of the result, and all instances of NEXT VALUE return the same value for a row of the result.

Notice that Db2 does not guarantee sequential numbers will be returned. So if your transaction rolls back, any previously consumed value from the sequence will not be returned in future - as long as the sequence is not reset at least.

Comment: So does it work like locking the data area? I will be using to create a sequence number per record.

Comment: The engine may lock the sequence-object, but that is not your concern, as Db2 guarantees that a new value will be returned per row of the result-set.